# Why is libuv timer drifting?

Tags: c++, timer, libuv, drift

While trying to implement a simple timer using libuv I noticed that the callback was "drifting". I am doing anything wrong here?

The code:

```
uv_timer_t timer;
uv_timer_init(uv_default_loop(), &timer);

double ts = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
timer.data = &ts;

uv_timer_start(&timer,
               [](uv_timer_t* handle) {
                 double* before = (double*)handle->data;
                 double now =
                     std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
                 auto diff = now - (*before);
                 is::log::info("tick... diff={}ns", diff);
                 *before = now;
               },
               1000, 1000);

uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
```

Output [libuv]: (diff always greater than 1.0s)

```
[info][10:48:26:636439] tick... diff=1.00083e+09ns
[info][10:48:27:637071] tick... diff=1.00063e+09ns
[info][10:48:28:638155] tick... diff=1.00108e+09ns
[info][10:48:29:639219] tick... diff=1.00106e+09ns
[info][10:48:30:640291] tick... diff=1.00107e+09ns
[info][10:48:31:641364] tick... diff=1.00107e+09ns
[info][10:48:32:641457] tick... diff=1.00009e+09ns
[info][10:48:33:642468] tick... diff=1.00101e+09ns
[info][10:48:34:643621] tick... diff=1.00115e+09ns
[info][10:48:35:644701] tick... diff=1.00108e+09ns
```

Equivalent libev code works perfectly.

Code:

```
ev_timer timer;

double ts = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
timer.data = &ts;

ev_timer_init(&timer,
              [](struct ev_loop*, ev_timer* handle, int) {
                double* before = (double*)handle->data;
                double now =
                    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
                auto diff = now - (*before);
                is::log::info("tick... diff={}ns", diff);
                *before = now;
              },
              1.0, 1.0);

ev_timer_start(EV_DEFAULT, &timer);
ev_run(EV_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Output [libev]:

```
[info][10:54:01:624788] tick... diff=1.00015e+09ns
[info][10:54:02:624943] tick... diff=1.00016e+09ns
[info][10:54:03:625035] tick... diff=1.00009e+09ns
[info][10:54:04:625177] tick... diff=1.00014e+09ns
[info][10:54:05:624284] tick... diff=9.99106e+08ns
[info][10:54:06:624415] tick... diff=1.00013e+09ns
[info][10:54:07:624533] tick... diff=1.00012e+09ns
[info][10:54:08:624592] tick... diff=1.00006e+09ns
[info][10:54:09:625245] tick... diff=1.00065e+09ns
[info][10:54:10:624331] tick... diff=9.99086e+08ns
```

### Solution

Implemented my own timer compensation logic that starts a new timer with the "correct" timeout on each iteration.

```
using namespace std::chrono;

struct Timer {
  uv_loop_t* loop;
  uv_timer_t timer;
  uint64_t period;
  time_point<high_resolution_clock> ref;

  Timer(uv_loop_t* loop, uint64_t period)
      : loop(loop), period(period), ref(high_resolution_clock::now() + milliseconds(period)) {
    uv_timer_init(loop, &timer);
    timer.data = this;
    uv_timer_start(&timer, callback, period, 0);
  }

  static void callback(uv_timer_t* handle) {
    auto self = (Timer*)handle->data;
    {
      auto delta = self->ref - high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto delta_count = duration_cast<milliseconds>(delta).count();
      is::log::info("tick... delta={}ms", delta_count);
    }

    { 
      self->ref = self->ref + milliseconds(self->period);
      auto delta = self->ref - high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto delta_count = duration_cast<milliseconds>(delta).count();
      uv_timer_start(&self->timer, self->callback, delta_count, 0);
    }
  }
};

Timer timer(uv_default_loop(), 1000);
uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
```

Output:

```
[info][14:20:19:772354] tick... delta=-1ms
[info][14:20:20:771120] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:21:772235] tick... delta=-1ms
[info][14:20:22:771040] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:23:772174] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:24:771302] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:25:771448] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:26:771568] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:27:771117] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:28:772250] tick... delta=-1ms
[info][14:20:29:771374] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:30:771495] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:31:771608] tick... delta=0ms
[info][14:20:32:771691] tick... delta=0ms
```

Comment: Don't count on timers being accurate. Even the hardware is not all too accurate.

Comment: comparison based on the same timer source, there shouldn't be a drift if design was ok.

Answer (score 3):

libuv repeating timers make no adjustments for the time their callback takes. They are re-engaged for the duration of the repeat interval right before the callback is called, see here: https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/timer.c#L165

There are people who look at it both ways, so in order to adjust your expectations I suggest you use a single-shot timer and rearm it in the callback as you see fit, just as you did.

On hindsight, I wish we didn't include repeating timers.

Comment: this is considered as a bug, millisecond scale drift cannot be explained by the callback function which just prints.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't properly drifting. It has a longer (let me say) *delay* probably due to the fact that the callback is scheduled on the first iteration that takes place after `t` milliseconds.
Actually, libev has a similar behavior, even worse if you consider that sometimes the callback is scheduled before the time is expired (at least in your example).
Note that a timer doesn't offer a strict schedule, but a best effort approach (that is, it executes the callback as soon as possible after the interval - as a not-so-good example, what happens if you have 100 CPU bound processes that fire all at the same time? You can't expect all the callbacks to have no delay at all).

Comment: Not sure if I agree with you here. If I schedule a timer to execute something every second, after 1000 seconds
I would expect it to execute that something 1000 times. But with the libuv "drift" of approximatelly 1ms it will only be 
executed 999 times. Therefore, in my opinion, the libev timer is the correct one here, since it adjusts itself to solve the "drift" problem.
To conclude, I expect the callback to have a delay (due to cpu bound processes, like you mentioned), but the timer should always try to compensate that delay on each iteration by scheduling the next tick earlier.

Comment: @RodolfoPicoreti It's the expectation that is wrong, even if I understand it. Anyway each time it `re-starts` itself it's as if you started a new independent timer with its own start point (that shares nothing but a data structure with the previous one). Therefore there is no room for a compensation. I'm not saying that your expectation is wrong in general, it simply doesn't apply to the specific case. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up implementing my own timer logic to get the behavior I wanted (I'll edit my question and add it there).